# 'Hiding' form query from URL (Django 1.3)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form with 6-7 fields. After user input, my webapp searches for those fields in a database and displays the results.
Now the issue is, that the URL ends up having all the form field names and their values in it.

```
result/?name=lorem&class=arc&course=ipsum
```

Now with the form having 7-8 fields the url ends up looking ugly.
Is there a Django technique to 'hide' these from the URL? Quotes around hide because I'd be okay with a completely different way to pass the objects to my database from the form as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).  Here's the [django docs on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and a [specific example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) using POST>. HTML-wise, all you need to do is change the method on the `form` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend to use POST requests for search. If you'll use GET it will be easer for user, he can just bookmark a link and save search or share search results with friends.